# Error running pod install, while running flutter build ios on Mac mini via Codemagic

Tags: ios, flutter, ipa, codemagic

I have a Flutter app that is successfully published on Google play store, but I am not able to publish on Apple play store because I constantly get errors while building the ipa file.
Because I don't have a Mac I use Codemagic, there I get this error:

```
%flutter build ios
Building nl.zonnebloemsoftware.seeyoubridgedummy for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 7GXYSLU63N
Running pod install...                                             502ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    [!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:108:in `compute_targets'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:40:in `compute_results'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1197:in `block (3 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `each'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `each'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in `analyze'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
```

Codemagic gives the option to connect remotely to the Mac Mini M1 machine. Running the same command with verbose options gives:

```
%flutter build ios --verbose 
...
...
[        ] Running pod install...
[ +454 ms] Running pod install... (completed in 450ms)
[        ] CocoaPods' output:
           ↳
[        ]       Preparing

               Analyzing dependencies

               Inspecting targets to integrate
                 Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
               [!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:108:in `compute_targets'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:40:in `compute_results'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1197:in `block (3 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `each'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `each'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in `analyze'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/bin/pod:25:in `load'
               /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

[   +1 ms] "flutter ios" took 2,701ms.
[   +1 ms] Error running pod install
[        ]
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      CocoaPods._runPodInstall (package:flutter_tools/src/macos/cocoapods.dart:347:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      CocoaPods.processPods (package:flutter_tools/src/macos/cocoapods.dart:170:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      processPodsIfNeeded (package:flutter_tools/src/macos/cocoapod_utils.dart:43:30)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      buildXcodeProject (package:flutter_tools/src/ios/mac.dart:226:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      _BuildIOSSubCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:650:37)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[   +1 ms] Running 0 shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

I have also tried to uncomment this line in ios/Podfile

## platform :ios, '11.0'

but this gives the same error

Note everything looks fine on the build machine see:

```
builder@builders-Virtual-Machine seeyoubridgedummy 
% flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable at /Users/builder/programs/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 84a1e904f4 (7 days ago), 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
    • Engine revision d44b5a94c9
    • Dart version 3.0.0
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /usr/local/share/android-sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /usr/local/share/android-sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /usr/local/share/android-sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode-14.3.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.92

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is not really enough information in the log snippets you have included to debug what the issue is. If you are about to post your question on Codemagics GitHub Discussions and include the build id of your build, the support team should be able to help you further https://github.com/orgs/codemagic-ci-cd/discussions

Comment: The codemagic build id = 646346a230f57af34c5b4d8d

Answer (score 0):

```
environment:
    flutter: 3.7.12
    xcode: 14.2
```

Try to specify flutter version same as your local flutter version instead of stable